# Code that has run smoothly for days suddenly not working. Not sure how to fix the exception that is being thrown

Tags: debugging, swift, ios8

I have a piece of code that has been running smoothly since I created it, that has suddenly begun to crash every time I run my app. I keep getting EXC_BREAKPOINT that highlights a line in my Thread 1 that states: Swift._getImplicitlyUnwrappedOptionalValue. I've tried adding breakpoints to catch the suspect code within my method, but nothing turns up and I just keep getting this error. I've been at this for a while now, and I'm pretty stumped as to what is going on and how I'm supposed to fix it. Any help is appreciated! Below I've included a screenshot of the error as well as the method I'm trying to call that produces the error. Thanks!

[image]

```
    @IBAction func nextPhoto(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    self.deleteResponseMessage(self)

    if photoObjects.count == 0
    {
        var image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "launchImageTall")
        feedView.image = image
    }

    else
    {
        userInfo.hidden = false

        var content:PFObject = photoObjects[0] as PFObject
        var recipients = content["recipients"] as NSMutableArray
        var userImageFile = content["imageFile"] as PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                var contentImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.feedView.image = contentImage
            }
        }
        var profilePicImageFile = content["senderProfilePic"] as PFFile
        profilePicImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                var picture = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.senderProfilePic.image = picture
            }
        })

        var username = content["senderUsername"] as NSString
        senderUsername.text = username
        var photoCaption = content["photoCaption"] as NSString
        senderMessage.text = photoCaption
        senderObjectId = content["senderObjectId"] as NSString

        for var i=0;i<photoObjects.count-1;i++
        {
            photoObjects[i] = photoObjects[i+1]
        }

        if recipients.count == 1
        {
            content.deleteInBackground()
        }
        else
        {
            recipients.removeObject(currentUserObjectId!)
            content.setObject(recipients, forKey: "recipients")
            content.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update Xcode recently. Apple is busy updating their cocoa libraries. Every return value was explicitly being unwrapped (like return String!). Now they are going through every function and evaluating whether it should return an instance (return String) or an optional (String?).

So check your code for optionals and remove those ! or ?.

At least that was the case for me with every Xcode update.

Comment: I have the most recent version of Xcode, and I've had it since I started this project. My code does include a fair amount of optionals, but a lot of those Xcode prompted me to include. Like I said before however, my code was working last night, but when I tried running it this morning I got that error. Do you have any other ideas?...Thanks for the response!

Comment: 1) Clean the build (folder). 2) Add more breakpoints or 3) selectively comment out parts of your code. Narrow it down as much as you can. I am sure you can find the offending line code that way. BTW, are your sure your data still exists or is accessible?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Parse and I can still see the data that I'm trying to access on the data browser. I can also print out the variables associated with the data on my console. After cleaning the build I'm finally getting an error in my console stating "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". So at least that's a start. I believe the offending lines occur when I'm trying to getDataInBackground. What I don't understand though, is that I'm printing the data on to my console right before I try to access it. So i'm not quite sure why it's being returned as nil.

Comment: if you do println(), do you get ... or Optional(...)? Println can handle either but maybe your receiver can't. What does getDataInBackground do? Is it using queues? Are your importing in a background queue but displaying it on the main queue? It's a bad, bad idea to send data to UIKit or core data from a background queue. It will work for a while but inevitable it will bite you in the ass.

Comment: I don't get the "or Optional(...)" line you are talking about, but when I println() the content i'm trying to access, it returns a dictionary with all of the content's variables. The content class is a Photo, and the Photo's variables include: sender, recipients(array), imageFile which is a PFFile, etc... None of those are set to nil when I println(), so I know they're there. getDataInBackgroundWithBlock() is a Parse API method which makes an asynchronous call to the server to retrieve the imageFile, which is then converted into NSData so that I can convert it from there into a UIImage.

Comment: I guess this is me getting bitten in the ass, haha

Comment: oh, it's a third party library. Well using their async calls should be safe then (if they know what they are doing). Try this: don't fetch a picture from the server but use just a local file that you load with the standard UIImage or NSData or ... methods. If the stand-in data gets displayed properly, then you know its a problem with getDataInBackgroundWithBlock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62851/discussion-between-user965972-and-user3353890).